# Stop Recurse when folder is yyyy

Tags: powershell

I have something like the following:

```
foreach ($d in Get-ChildItem $logDirectory -Directory | Where-Object Name -ne "2019")
```

The first time it runs is fine as the folders don't exist (I'm creating them).  After that however the script is continuing to recurse through so I end up with this:

```
- logs
  - 2019
    - 12
    - 2019
      - 04
      - 12
      - 2019
```

I only want it to go through the folders that do not start recursing dates.  How do I do that?

Comment: Hi, the script you're showing us only searches the directories for folders that aren't named "2019" so we can't see what is causing the problem. Also, I think I know what you're looking for, but the last line (after the code block) doesn't make sense to me. Maybe elaborate on that?

Comment: @TheIdesOfMark is right. Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to move your `Get-ChildItem` outside your `foreach` loop. What is likely happening is that the `Get-ChildItem` is evaluated every time the loop iterates. This means that it picks up the newly created directories as the loop iterates, and starts iterating with them as well. Try first getting the directories and storing it in a variable:

```
$Directories = Get-ChildItem $logDirectory -Directory | Where-Object Name -ne "2019"
foreach ($d in $Directories)
...
```